# Row select on datatables not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to allow for row select on my datatables work (as seen here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_single_row.html) but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on where I might be going wrong?

I've included the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/v6VTB/2/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example5').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    });
});

var oTable;
var giRedraw = false;

/* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */
$("#example5 tbody").click(function (event) {
    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function () {
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
    $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
});

/* Add a click handler for the row */

/* Init the table */
oTable = $('#example5').dataTable();

/* Get the rows which are currently selected */
function fnGetSelected(oTableLocal) {
    var aReturn = new Array();
    var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

    for (var i = 0; i < aTrs.length; i++) {
        if ($(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected')) {
            aReturn.push(aTrs[i]);
        }
    }
    return aReturn;
}
```

Comment: asking for problems initializing the same plugin twice on the same table especially with different options. Will likely not break but mostly lead to later confusion thinking a set of options should be working but have actually been over written later in code

Answer (score 2):

the row_selected class is not been defined

see this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/v6VTB/3/ , added a example css below

```
.row_selected​{
    color:red;
}​
```